# cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations

Tags: wordpress, curl, path, certificate

I'm having trouble updating my Wordpress intall and plugin updates. I get this error or a slight variant of it with the plug ins:

---

Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /home/content/95/7663295/html/wp-admin/includes/update.php on line 122

Downloading update from http://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.7.3-no-content.zip…

Download failed.: cURL error 77: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /home/content/95/7663295/html/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none

Installation Failed

---

I haven't modified my certificate's path, so I'm not sure why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Check that wp-includes/certificates actually exists or try to replace the existing one. It's always handy to backup the existing directory by zipping it before replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

Solve in 5 mins.

Try to upload fresh certificate from the latest wp version.

**Steps**

1: get the certificates folder in /wp-includes/
2: Copy the ca-bundle.crt file to this folder from latest version of WP and then place in same folder where error shows.

**Why this issue come** -  sometime developers download complete site from live and then start development at demo server so it conflict.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but in my case I have a `.gitignore` with that excludes all `*.crt` files because I don't want my self-signed certs to make it into the repo.

That will *also* exclude the `/wp-includes/certificates/ca-bundle.crt` bundle file (see your error message). So, if you cloned or pulled on a different machine, then there is your reason for this error.

To solve this, my root `.gitignore` looks like this

```
...
*.key
*.crt
!ca-bundle.crt
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I solve the same issue, there will be two possibilities which I applied on my client's website.

1) make sure your openSSL enabled, if not then do it from cPanel. And change the url from WordPress general setting from **http to https**

2) check the file and folder permission in wp-include folder and inside other folders, permission should be 577.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading/updating plugins suddenly stopped working on my Wordpress site, and I got the same error message. When I checked my live site there's missing ***certificates*** folder in ***/wp-includes/***

Here's how I fixed my issue:

1. Create ***certificates*** folder in ***/wp-includes/***
2. Copy the ***ca-bundle.crt*** file to this folder from the same folder of a fresh copy of Wordpress

After that I was able to download/update plugins again